# How can i detect a particular color on a picture and get the height and width of the object in pixels?

Tags: python, image, height, pixel

I want to write a python script that recognizes a color on a jpg picture, and then measures the object's height / width in pixels.

So for example: there's a picture where a lot of things are located. I would like my program to be able to recognize the one object (in this case it's a rectangle) that is orange. After it does, i would like it to calculate the object's width and height in pixels.

How should i go about this? I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIL library in python, or OpenCV also.

for PIL installation:

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

for importing:

```
from PIL import Image
```

for reading image's height and width:

```
im = Image.open(yourImagePath)
height, width = im.size
```

where im is your image variable and yourImagePath should be replaced by your current image file path.